# How to rename REST routes in URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Give that I have a model called `Apple` and it has a controller `ApplesController`, the routes are:

```
resources :apples

    apples  GET    /apples (.:format)          {:controller=>"apples ", :action=>"index"}
  new_apple GET    /apples /new(.:format)      {:controller=>"apples ", :action=>"new"}
 edit_apple GET    /apples /:id/edit(.:format) {:controller=>"apples ", :action=>"edit"}
```

I would like to keep all code the same, except that in URLs, the "apple" would be replaced by "car". So, the URL `/apples/new` would become `/cars/new`.

Is there some way to do this while not touching any other code in the app? (i.e. internally in the app, it's still `apple` and `ApplesController`)

I tried `:as` option:

```
resources :apples, :as => "cars"

    cars    GET    /apples (.:format)          {:controller=>"apples ", :action=>"index"}
  new_car   GET    /apples /new(.:format)      {:controller=>"apples ", :action=>"new"}
 edit_car   GET    /apples /:id/edit(.:format) {:controller=>"apples ", :action=>"edit"}
```

But that only changed the "name" of the route, not the URL (so `new_apple_path` became `new_car_path`, but `new_car_path` still points to `/apples/new` instead of `/cars/new`)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

What you will want to do is pass in the `:path` option

`resources :apples, :path => "cars"`

This replace all your route references with `/apples` to `/cars`

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html, Section 4.7 Translating Paths

Comment: Just for completeness, in Rails 2.3 would have been: `resources :apples, :as => "cars"`

Comment: I am new to Rails (4), but as only changes the route helpers. The URLs generated don't change. :path => "xxx" changes the URLs

Answer (score 0):

For those seeking only to rename the helper method part:

```
resources :apples, as: "cars"
```

I.e. this would replace `apples_path` with `cars_path`, but still using the same controller/action.