# Rails 4: how to customize route key for a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `CourseQuestion` model in my app.

I use `redirect_to @discussible` in my controllers, where `@discussible` could be of different class (therefore redirect is to a different URL).

But I need to redirect `CourseQuestion` models to `question_path`, not `course_question_path` which is default.

I don't need to change routes (routes are fine), just need rails to deduce specific named path for a model.

Any good way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename REST routes in URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012255/how-to-rename-rest-routes-in-url)

Comment: I don't need to change routes (routes are fine), just need rails to deduce specific named route for a model.

Comment: Isn't this done with `resources :apples, :as => "cars"`, mentioned by the link?

Comment: `resources :apples, :as => "cars"` changes the routes. I need to fit model with existing route names.

Comment: As pointed out in [Rails Routing docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes), `:as` changes the named route helper according to its argument while keeping the route path intact. the `:path` option, in turn, modifies both. If this doesn't help you, please show your routes and relevant controller and models.

Comment: The point is that i don't want to change neither named routes nor pathes!

Answer (score 1):

Something I've done, but somehow feels like a hack is to override the model_name method of the model.

In your case, you could do:

```
class CourseQuestion
  def self.model_name
    ActiveModel::Name.new(self, nil, "Question")
  end

# if your course_question belongs_to :question, to prevent some unwanted bugs, where course_questions/25 would map to questions/25, add a to_param method that returns the id of the question, as such
  def to_param
   question_id.to_s # Be sure to stringify the id for routes
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks, I've come to the same solution but doesn't look like clean to me :)

Answer (score 1):

A questionable module to include in models, changing only `#route_key` and `#singular_route_key` methods:

```rb
module DemodulizedRouteKeys
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def model_name
      ## this would demodulize all namings:
      # ActiveModel::Name.new self, nil, super.name.demodulize
      super.tap do |name|
        route_key = name.name.demodulize.underscore
        name.define_singleton_method(:route_key) { route_key.pluralize }
        name.define_singleton_method(:singular_route_key) { route_key }
      end
    end
  end
end
```