# rename route on a static page ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

How can I rename my routes in rails, 
My original route is

```
get 'pages/fonctionnalites'
```

I tried to rename it like this to have only /fonctionnalites in my url :

```
get 'fonctionnalites' => 'pages#fonctionnalites'
```

My nav looks like this :

```
<div class="nav__panel">
    <ul class="nav__links">
        <li>
            <%= link_to 'Fonctionnalités',fonctionnalites_path, class: "nav__link" %>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But when I do so, when I click on the link, my page is not reloaded so the link goes nowhere, any idea how to rename it and reload the page to have content ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rename REST routes in URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012255/how-to-rename-rest-routes-in-url)

Comment: What do you mean by "when I click on the link, my page is not reloaded so the link goes nowhere"?

Comment: Show us your view code where the link is generated. If you change your route, you'll need to change the url helper or code.

Comment: thx for your help, I edited my nav page to allow you to check how i make the link, @EdgarOrtega by "goes nowhere" I mean that the URL path looks good but as the page is not reload, there is no content but when I refresh my content is loaded

Comment: If you are using turbolinks, try disabling it in your app/assets/js/application.js

Comment: Merci @EdgarOrtega it works now !